# Cron job command to not overwrite exising file when executed

Tags: cron, cronexpression

I'm using the following command

```
mysqldump -hHOST -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD DATABASE > file.sql
```

Would like a separate job created each time when `cron` job is executed and not overwrite existing file.

Answer (score 1):

i'm using shell scrip for solve this problem on my server. This is the code if you wan to try. Create file .sh, Ex: backupdb.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
NOW=$(date +"%m%d%Y")
FILE="backupdb.$NOW.tgz"
SQL="backupdb.$NOW.sql"
DBNAME='live'              #name of database
DUMP='/usr/bin/mysqldump'
USER='root'                #user
HOST=10.0.0.8              #Ip database

$DUMP -h $HOST -u $USER -pYOURPASSWORD --routines --events $DBNAME > /home/backupdb/$SQL

gzip -9 /home/backupdb/$SQL
echo "BACKUP DATABASES FROM MYSQL MASTER SUCCESS $SQL"|mail -s "BACKUP DATABASES" your@email.com         #you can chang this email with your personal email
```

and save.

Don't forget to change permission,

```
chmod +x backupdb.sh
```

Add this code in cron job

```
00 04 *  *  * sh /home/backupdb/backupdb.sh
```

Save

That's it.

Sorry if my English is not good